# Reharper runner plugins for xunit and mspec simultaniously

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, xunit.net, mspec, xunit

I have successfully used the Resharper 4.5 runner for xunit tests in vs2008. Now I want to try out MSpec and I want to use the Resharper 4.5 runner for MSpec. But I have them both installed I get an error message when starting Visual Studio, that a plugin can not be loaded, because there is already a plugin with the same name loaded.

Is it possible to have the two plugins loaded simultaniously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSpec and the xUnit plugins are in no way connected to each other in that they share code or their name.

I suspect you did put one of the plugins in two places such that it is loaded twice with the the second load failing. I've used both plugins myself for a while, so there should be no issue.

Please check you plugin list via ReSharper | Plugins and see if there's duplicate entry for any those plugins. One should have the checkbox unticked.

Make sure that both the xUnit and the MSpec plugin are only deployed once in directories ReSharper searches for plugins. This is:

- `c:\Program Files\JetBrains\ReSharper\v4.5\Bin\Plugins`
  and
- `c:\Users\<user
  name>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\v4.5\vs9.0\Plugins\`

for ReSharper 4.5 and Visual Studio 2008, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is pretty strange. They are only installed once. If I have one of them installed alone, it works fine. I have tried both directories for installation, and the result is the same. It works ok, when there is one of them installed. Installing them both, I get an error.

Comment: And suddenly it works. It seems, that if I have the one plugin in the users dir and the other in the app dir, it fails. I can make no sense of this, though :) ... And still only one plugin is shown in the plugins overview. Thanks for your answer.